# Get and set the active row in QTreeview programmatically (PyQt)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

Is there a way to get and change the active row in a QTreeView (not QTreeWidget)? By active, I mean the row with the focus highlight, not the selected row. In the paint event, I can use `QStyle.State_HasFocus` to get the active row, but this doesn't seem to work elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get/set the active row with the `currentIndex()` and `setCurrentIndex()` functions that you can find in both `QTreeView` and `QItemSelectionModel` (the latter is returned by `QTreeView.selectionModel()`).

And despite its name, the `QItemSelectionModel` handles the view current item, and the view selection independently.

Answer (score 1):

Current item is the one which is indicated by the focus rectangle. You can change it using [selectionModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) function of the tree view. If you don't want to change currently selected items, pass QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.NoUpdate as a second parameter to [setCurrentIndex](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qitemselectionmodel.html#setCurrentIndex) method. Below is an example:

```
index = model.index(3, 0);
view.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(index, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.NoUpdate)
```

this should move current item to the item with index 3

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 0):

For me it got nothing here new to ask such question, why because simple; you can use Qt-Designer and create `QTreeView` and then create line edit, then link them using the action editor, then transform the UI file to Py file, then you will see how things work behind the scene.
You will find this if you try:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.treeView, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked(QModelIndex)")), self.test)
```